# Achartengine label axis x

Tags: android, achartengine, axis-labels

I'm using `AChartEngine` to create a `Bar Graph`: on the `x axis`,I have strings made by name and surname. For example, "John Smith". Is that possible to write this label on more lines? 
Like John (other line, as /r)  Smith ?  Hope you can help. Thanks for interesting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, like below:

```
renderer.addXTextLabel(0.5, "line1\nline2");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try it as soon as possible and let you know! :)

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! Can i ask something else? How can I hide the legend? I know that using setMargins is not the right way to do this...

Comment: you have right, sorry, i didn't made a good search on the site ;) thanks!

Comment: renderer.setShowLegend(false);

Comment: is it possible to set the margins on legend , as its by default attached to the screen??